# How to make sure a name string of storyboard in an iOS project is right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uistoryboard

In iOS project:

I always create a UIViewController by UIStroyboard in this way.
 swift:

```
       let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "XXXlectViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

objective -c

```
       UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"XXXlectViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Then I access a UIViewController form the storyboard.

If somebody else changes the name string accidentally. This project would not work as expected.

Sometimes, I can't make sure that the string typed by me is correct.

As you know, If I create a UIViewContrller by using pure code.

`let xxxVC = xxxVC()`

`XXXVC *vc = [[XXXVC alloc] init];`

When I Command B/R, I will get the error alert. This can help us to spot the error.

How to make sure a name string of storyboard in an iOS project is right?
How to reduce the danger of this way which uses storyboard to create UIViewControll instance?
Do you use the Unit text to check the UIViewController created by UIStoryboard?
How can I do it?

Comment: You can't. But you might be interested in SwiftGen or R.Swift which will parse your ressources and make them by "code" into vars.

Comment: Have you considered using a constants file and referring to it?

Answer (score -1):

For Objective-C, you can declare your storyboard names as constants and use them in your code.

In your `.h` file

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const MainStoryboaardIdentifier;
```

In your `.m` file

```
NSString *const MainStoryboaardIdentifier = @"Main";
```

And for swift, the easiest can be defining an enum for them:

```
enum StoryboardIdentifier: String {
    case Login = "Login"
    case Main = "Main"
    case Options = "Options"
}
```

and use `.Main` or `.Login`.

This way the auto-complete will also work and mistyping can be avoided. Furthermore, unit testing should also be easier. Using a specific identifier in the `UIStoryboard` initializer should result in the respective viewController.

Comment: That doesn't answer the user's question. He's worried the name in code may not match the name of the file.

Comment: That's where the tests come around